# Cannot find "Locale" entry in KDE System Settings

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, locale

Several guides require me to open the <kbd>Locale</kbd> menu in the KDE System Settings. Unfortunately, on my system there is no such menu. In the Appearance section, where it should reside, I only see "Workspace Theme", "Color", "Font", "Icons", and "Application Style".

What could be going on here? Am I missing a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Kubuntu 18.04, not 16.04, but I think the approach should be similar.

Open `System Settings` and type `locale` in the search bar.

You should see `Regional Settings` appear:

[image: System Settings]

When you open `Regional Settings`, you may see something like this:

[image: locale]

Scroll down to choose the locale you desire.

---

If instead of typing `locale`, you type `language`, you'll see different choices under `Regional Settings` as shown below:

[image: Language]

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure if this was the right entry, since some of the option have been moved to the input devices entry since 14.04. So, I wasn't missing anything, the entry was just renamed and reorganized.